# Returning a value from one method to another to be used in the output

Tags: java, methods, printing, return

I can't figure out how to return the value of finalCost to the main method and have it printed.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PhonePlan {
    private static double basecost = 8.5;
    private static double rate = 0.35;
    private static double discount = 0.15;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scan input for downloadLimit
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the download limit in GB: ");
        int downloadLimit = scan.nextInt();
        // Call other method
        calcMonthlyCharge(downloadLimit);

        System.out.println("Plan monthly cost: " + calcMonthlyCharge(finalCost));
    }

    public static double calcMonthlyCharge(double downloadLimit) {
        // Calculate final cost
        double fullCost = downloadLimit * rate + basecost;
        double planDiscount = fullCost * discount;
        double finalCost = fullCost - planDiscount;
        return finalCost;
    }
}
```

Specifically, I can't find how to use the returned value in the "println" line.

```
    System.out.println("Plan monthly cost: " + calcMonthlyCharge(finalCost) ); 
} 
public static double calcMonthlyCharge(double downloadLimit) { 
    // Calculate final cost 
    double fullCost = downloadLimit * rate + basecost; 
    double planDiscount = fullCost * discount; 
    double finalCost = fullCost - planDiscount; 
    return finalCost;
}
```

Comment: Store the returned value of `calcMonthlyCharge` to some local variable and print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `calcMonthlyCharge(downloadLimit)`,but don't store the returnvalue.

When you call  `System.out.println("Plan monthly cost: " + calcMonthlyCharge(finalCost) );`
It is unknown what finalcost is, this is a variable which only exist in the scope of calcMonthlyCharge

Either store the returnvalue of `calcMonthlyCharge(downloadLimit)` and reuse the value to print, or use `calcMonthlyCharge(downloadLimit)` in your `println` with downloadLimit as parameter to get a new returnvalue.